# swagger Couldn't find constant type

Tags: swagger

I am having a little trouble generating my json file. Here is what I am trying to compiler that is giving me an error, some code has changed to protect my work:

```
/** 
* @SWG\Post( 
*     path="/path", * summary="summary of post", 
*     @SWG\Response( 
*         response=100,description="Success" * ), 
*         @SWG\Parameter( 
*             name="parameters", 
*             description="parameters are passed", 
*             in="body", 
*             @SWG\Schema( 
*             type="object", 
*             required={ 
*                 "req1", 
*                 "req2", 
*                 "req3", 
*             }, 
*             properties={ 
*                 "req1"={ 
*                     type="number", 
*                     format="int64" 
*                 }, 
*                 "req2"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "req3"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param1"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param2"={ 
*                     type="number", 
*                     format="int64" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param3"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param4"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param5"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param6"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param7"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param8"={ 
*                     type="number", 
*                     format="int64" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param9"={ 
*                     type="string", 
*                     format="date-time" 
*                 }, 
*                 "param10"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p11"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p12"={ 
*                     type="number", 
*                     format="int64" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p13"={ 
*                     type="number", 
*                     format="int64" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p14"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p15"={ 
*                     type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p16"={ 
*                    type="string" 
*                 }, 
*                 "p17"={ 
*                    type="string" 
*                 } 
*            } 
*        ) 
*     ) 
* ) 
*/
```

But I am getting this error:

> [WARN] [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant type, \Path->index_post() in /path/to/file.php on line 7.

Any help to resolve this issue would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe problem in `*` after `path="/path",`

My swagger example

```
 /**
 * @SWG\Post(path="/v1/users",
 *   tags={"user"},
 *   summary="Create a user",
 *   description="This can only be done by the logged user.",
 *   operationId="createUser",
 *   produces={"application/xml", "application/json"},
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two leftover `*` symbols in your definition.
You probably meant to add a newline before them?

`path="/path", *` <-- One line above @SWG\Response
`description="Success" * ),` <-- One line below @SWG\Response